# Time series in Cassandra when measures can go "back in time"

Tags: time, cassandra, cql, series

this is related to [cassandra time series modeling when time can go backward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628735/cassandra-time-series-modeling-when-time-can-go-backward), but I think I have a better scenario to explain why the topic is important.

Imagine I have a simple table

```
CREATE TABLE measures(
 key text,
 measure_time timestamp,
 value int, 
 PRIMARY KEY (key, measure_time))
 WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (measure_time DESC);
```

The purpose of the clustering key is to have data arranged in a decreasing timestamp ordering. This leads to very efficient range-based queries, that for a given key lead to sequential disk reading (which are intrinsically fast).

Many times I have seen suggestions to use a generated timeuuid as timestamp value ( using now() ), and this is obviously intrinsically ordered. But you can't always do that. It seems to me a very common pattern, you can't use it if:

1) your user wants to query on the actual time when the measure has been *taken*, not the time where the measure has been *written*.

2) you use multiple writing threads

So, I want to understand what happens if I write data in an unordered fashion (with respect to measure_time column).

I have personally tested that if I insert timestamp-unordered values, Cassandra indeed reports them to me in a timestamp-ordered fashion when I run a select.

But what happens "under the hood"? In my opinion, it is impossible that data are still ordered on disk. At some point in fact data need to be flushed on disk. Imagine you flush a data set in the time range [0,10]. What if the next data set to flush has measures with timestamp=9? Are data re-arranged on disk? At what cost?

Hope I was clear, I couldn't find any explanation about this on Datastax site but I admit I'm quite a novice on Cassandra. Any pointers appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Sure, once written a SSTable file is immutable, Your timestamp=9 will end up in another SSTable, and C* will have to merge and sort data from both SSTables, if you'll request both timestamp=10 and timestamp=9. And that would be less effective than reading from a single SSTable.

The Compaction process may merge those two SSTables into new single one. See http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/when-to-use-leveled-compaction

And try to avoid very wide rows/partitions, which will be the case if you have a lot measurements (i.e. a lot of `measure_time` values) for a  single `key`.

Comment: good explanation and very good link, I need to spend some time to understand what is the best option for my use case